# android TimerTask blocks ui

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I use a TimerTask for updating my UI. The problem is when the timer is running my seekbar blocks. The timer is called every 500 ms and sets a display icon.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    Timer _connectTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        control = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek);

        control.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
        {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
            {
                progressChanged = progress;

                _stringProcess = Integer.toString(progress);

                if(progressChanged > (_oldProgress + 10) || progressChanged < (_oldProgress - 10))
                {

                  new Thread(new Runnable() 
                  {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            try 
                            {
                                doSomething();
                            } 
                            catch (IOException e) 
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } 
                            catch (FormatException e) 
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                  }).start();
                 _oldProgress = progress;
                }       
    }

    //called by the timer
    public void updateConnectStatus()
    {
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view_conn)).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        _connectTimer = new Timer();
        _connectTimer.schedule(new ConnectTimer(new Handler(), this),0,500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        _connectTimer.cancel();
        _connectTimer.purge();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}




public class ConnectTimer extends TimerTask
{
    Handler _handler;
    MainActivity _mainActivity;

    public ConnectTimer(Handler handler, MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        super();
        _handler = handler;
        _mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        _handler.post(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                _mainActivity.updateConnectStatus();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting NDEF message from tag freezes Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389126/getting-ndef-message-from-tag-freezes-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the following line:

```
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view_conn)).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

It's time consuming operation: searching view hierarchy to find `ImageView` and setting image which read and decode bitmap on the UI thread.

To do something about it, first of all call `((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view_conn))` only once inside `onCreate()` method and keep reference to that `ImageView`. So your code could look like this:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

Secondly, instead `setImageResource()` you can call `setImageBitmap()` preceding with loading bitmap in a separate thread.

In this solution I assumed that mentioned line is just an example. If not, I don't know what is the point to repeat setting the same icon over and over again.

Also I assumed that `doSomething()` is not doing any UI operation from background thread which is prohibited.

You can also consider taking different approach and change your icon only when it's really needed, not every 500ms.

Comment: yes the solution is only an example. you are right my solution was to time consuming. thank you for the help.

Comment: If that answer works for you please mark is as correct. If not, try applying proposed solution and update your question if it's still not working.